# Build XML file based off CSV list using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, loops, csv, foreach

I have a CSV file with a layout shown below:

```
Region,Store,Number,IP Address,Store Number
Central,ABC,111,127.0.0.1,1234
Central,CDE,222,127.0.0.1,5678
Central,EFG,333,127.0.0.1,9101
Central,HIJ,444,127.0.0.1,1213
Central,KLM,555,127.0.0.1,1415
```

I need to build an XML file as listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.8.0_271" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookEntry">
  <void property="country">
   <string>USA</string>
  </void>
  <void property="ipAddress">
   <string>127.0.0.1</string>
  </void>
  <void property="name">
   <string>111 ABC</string>
  </void>
  <void property="storeNumber">
   <string>1234</string>
  </void>
 </object>
 <object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookGroup">
  <void property="name">
   <string>[None]</string>
  </void>
 </object>
 <object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookGroup">
  <void property="name">
   <string>Imported Entries</string>
  </void>
 </object>
 <object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookGroup">
  <void property="name">
   <string>Duplicated Entries</string>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
```

I need to pull each line from the CSV file and add it into the middle of the xml, should look something like this.

Top section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.8.0_271" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
```

Loop through the CSV file line by line pulling out each location, this is how the middle section should look:

```
 <object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookEntry">
  <void property="country">
   <string>USA</string>
  </void>
  <void property="ipAddress">
   <string>127.0.0.1</string>
  </void>
  <void property="name">
   <string>111 ABC</string>
  </void>
  <void property="storeNumber">
   <string>1234</string>
  </void>
 </object>
 <object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookEntry">
  <void property="country">
   <string>USA</string>
  </void>
  <void property="ipAddress">
   <string>127.0.0.1</string>
  </void>
  <void property="name">
   <string>222 CDE</string>
  </void>
  <void property="storeNumber">
   <string>5678</string>
  </void>
 </object>
```

Then add the bottom section of the XML which looks like this:

```
 <object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookGroup">
  <void property="name">
   <string>[None]</string>
  </void>
 </object>
 <object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookGroup">
  <void property="name">
   <string>Imported Entries</string>
  </void>
 </object>
 <object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookGroup">
  <void property="name">
   <string>Duplicated Entries</string>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
```

Currently this is the code I've been working on and it loops through but it's all the last store in my CSV file. I haven't worried about adding the top or bottom of the XML yet until I get this part right.

```
$xmlpath = "test.xml"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$Stores = Import-Csv -Path "Stores.csv"

    foreach($Loc in $Stores){
        $StoreName = '{0}' -f $Loc.Store
        $Number = '{0}' -f $Loc.Number
        $IP = '{0}' -f $Loc."IP Address"
        $StoreNum = '{0}' -f $Loc."Store Number"


        try {
$entryTemplate = @'
 <object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookEntry">
  <void property="country">
   <string>USA</string>
  </void>
  <void property="ipAddress">
   <string>$IP</string>
  </void>
  <void property="name">
   <string>$Number $StoreName</string>
  </void>
  <void property="storeNumber">
   <string>$StoreNum</string>
  </void>
 </object>
'@

$xml = $data | ForEach-Object {
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($entrytemplate)
}
$xml | Out-File $xmlpath
        }
        catch {
            Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it :

```
$GlobalXML=@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.8.0_271" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 {0}
 <object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookGroup">
  <void property="name">
   <string>[None]</string>
  </void>
 </object>
 <object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookGroup">
  <void property="name">
   <string>Imported Entries</string>
  </void>
 </object>
 <object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookGroup">
  <void property="name">
   <string>Duplicated Entries</string>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
'@

$PartXML=@'
<object class="client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookEntry">
  <void property="country">
   <string>USA</string>
  </void>
  <void property="ipAddress">
   <string>{0}</string>
  </void>
  <void property="name">
   <string>{1} {2}</string>
  </void>
  <void property="storeNumber">
   <string>{3}</string>
  </void>
 </object>
'@

$PartText=""

import-csv "C:\temp\test.csv" | %{

$PartText+=$PartXML -f $_."IP Address", $_.Number, $_.Store, $_."Store Number"

}

$GlobalXML -f $PartText| Out-File "c:\temp\result.xml" -encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Great answer, worked like a charm. Very easy to follow your code I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
param(
   $csvFileName = "d:\tmp\data.csv"
)

@"
Region,Store,Number,IP Address,Store Number
Central,ABC,111,127.0.0.1,1234
Central,CDE,222,127.0.0.1,5678
Central,EFG,333,127.0.0.1,9101
Central,HIJ,444,127.0.0.1,1213
Central,KLM,555,127.0.0.1,1415
"@ | out-file $csvFileName

$XMLDocument = [xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.8.0_271" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
</java>
"@

$javaNode = $XMLDocument.SelectSingleNode("/java")

Import-Csv -Path $csvFileName | ForEach-Object {
   $objectNode = $javaNode.AppendChild($XMLDocument.CreateElement("object"))
   $objectNodeClassAtribute = $XMLDocument.CreateAttribute("class")
   $objectNodeClassAtribute.Value = "client.remoteaccess.model.AddressBookEntry"
   $objectNode.Attributes.Append($objectNodeClassAtribute)

   $voidNode = $objectNode.AppendChild($XMLDocument.CreateElement("void"))
   $voidNodePropertyAtribute = $XMLDocument.CreateAttribute("property")
   $voidNodePropertyAtribute.Value = "Country"
   $voidNode.Attributes.Append($voidNodePropertyAtribute)

   $StringNode = $voidNode.AppendChild($XMLDocument.CreateElement("string"))
   $StringNode.InnerText = "USA"
   
   $voidNode = $objectNode.AppendChild($XMLDocument.CreateElement("void"))
   $voidNodePropertyAtribute = $XMLDocument.CreateAttribute("property")
   $voidNodePropertyAtribute.Value = "ipAddress"
   $voidNode.Attributes.Append($voidNodePropertyAtribute)

   $StringNode = $voidNode.AppendChild($XMLDocument.CreateElement("string"))
   $StringNode.InnerText = $_."IP Address"
   
   $voidNode = $objectNode.AppendChild($XMLDocument.CreateElement("void"))
   $voidNodePropertyAtribute = $XMLDocument.CreateAttribute("property")
   $voidNodePropertyAtribute.Value = "name"
   $voidNode.Attributes.Append($voidNodePropertyAtribute)

   $StringNode = $voidNode.AppendChild($XMLDocument.CreateElement("string"))
   $StringNode.InnerText = "{0} {1}" -f $_.Store, $_.Number

   $voidNode = $objectNode.AppendChild($XMLDocument.CreateElement("void"))
   $voidNodePropertyAtribute = $XMLDocument.CreateAttribute("property")
   $voidNodePropertyAtribute.Value = "storeNumber"
   $voidNode.Attributes.Append($voidNodePropertyAtribute)

   $StringNode = $voidNode.AppendChild($XMLDocument.CreateElement("string"))
   $StringNode.InnerText = $_."Store Number"
}
$XMLDocument.Save("d:\tmp\out.xml")
```

Comment: Both answers worked here, thank you for the advice this helps